# Показывать рекламу один раз в день через DateTime.now

Tags: c#, datetime

Доброго времени суток, не совсем понятно каким образом реализовать следующую задачу: есть реклама, она должна вызываться в игре один раз в день, на следующий день, на следующий день реклама снова доступна к просмотру. То есть нажали на кнопку "1" показалась реклама, на второе нажатие уже будут другие действия, после наступления нового дня, реклама снова показывается один раз и так по кругу, подскажите как такое реализовать, буду признателен за шаблонный код или источники по сути этого вопроса.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
public class Day : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text textNow;


public  void CheckDate()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Parse ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Session"));
        if (now < (int)DateTime.Now.ToString())
        {
            textNow.text = "Можем показывать рекламу";
        } else textNow.text = "Превышен лимит на день";

    }


    public  void setSaveDate()
    {

        PlayerPrefs.SetString ("Session", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"));
        CheckDate ();
    }
}
```

Comment: а нет возможности сохранять дату последнего показа и если от этой даты прошли сутки, то показывать снова?

Comment: Такое настраивается на уровне рекламных сетей, а не в коде.

Comment: был вариант просто сравнивать день, если день, который запомнили, меньше чем текущий, тогда разрешаем показывать рекламу.. но что то с кодом не очень разобрался, запоминаю в стринг 'DateTime.Now.ToString("dd")' а как конвектировать в целое число, что бы сравнить не знаю, добавил код в правки.
Рекламная сеть новая, мне сказали это вручную у себя в коде написать..

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так вычисляется промежуток времени для вашей задачи.

```csharp
    private DateTime timeLeft { get; set; }

    private void Rec()
    {
        TimeSpan timeSpan = timeLeft.AddDays(1).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
        if (timeSpan > TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            // показать рекламу
        }
    }
```

где `timeLeft` это время последнего показа рекламы.

вы можете его зашифровать и установить в сессию пользователю , или сохранить на сервере

Comment: Может быть `TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeLeft.NowAddDays(1));`?

Comment: По моему мнению как раз у вас результат будет отрицательный, поэтому и написал. Now больше чем last + 1, из меньшего вычитаешь большее и получаешь отрицательное число.

Comment: Пример с ошибкой ваш, я только местами поменял части.

Comment: мой код : `TimeSpan timeSpan = timeLeft.AddDays(1).Subtract(DateTime.Now);`
ВАШ КОД : `TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeLeft.NowAddDays(1));`

Comment: Да, subtract вы правильно написали, проверил, тут моя ошибка. А вот код для теста вашего примера - https://ideone.com/Z15rtI видим что он показывает рекламу после того как 5 минут назад уже показал одну

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75280/discussion-between-digital-core-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Может есть смысл хранить ещё одну переменную?

```
public bool advShown = false;

public  void CheckDate()
    {

        DateTime now = DateTime.Parse ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetString ("Session"));
        if (now < (int)DateTime.Now.ToString() && advShown == false)
        {
            textNow.text = "Можем показывать рекламу";
            advShown = true;
        } else textNow.text = "Превышен лимит на день";

    }
```